# require.js multiple including

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I try to search the issue I'm facing, but I found it's hard to get an answer, so I ask here.

I use `require.js` to decompose my project.

the structure is:

```
main.js 

a.js

b.js

c.js
```

and the dependencies is:

> c needs a
>
> b needs a
>
> main needs a, b, c

so `a.js` will be included for twice, it works correctly, but I don't know whether this is the best way to use require.js

Comment: RequireJS is supposed to manage dependencies, so that `a.js` is only loaded once in your case. Can you verify it is loaded multiple times, i.e. can you see the network calls (Firebug net tab)? If so, you either have a configuration error (please post code), or you have found a RequireJS bug (unlikely, but stil a possibility).

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I look up the network tab in my chrome, it didn't include multiple time. Thanks a lot